# Need Suggestion about google map filtering and saving data to DB

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im starting to create a project about google maps..I have created a map with my own api key..But adding the markers was a bit dizzy to me..So, I went to go and switch for a 3rd party google map that it have created already the maps.

Is there any 3rd party google map I can used and Is there a way, on how I can connect it to the Database.Using PHP and MySql??

Anyone any suggestion on how??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up your computer with PHPmyAdmin. There are a couple of sources that you can download it for free. You will turn your computer into a server.

Then you need to spend some time with the google tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3). that's the first step. Cutting corners will not help down the road....
You will see people prefer json to xml. But the google tutorials bring xml if I am not mistaken. 
The tutorials almost never work out of the box.... but as you struggle, you will learn. 
There are the tutorials from Mike Williams [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/).

The filter part is more complex stuff, that can be done in the back end with php/mysql or front end at the browser. Simple filters are part of many tutorials in the net (like radius). I am still trying to figure out how to do complex filters.
It seems that it depends on the load, speed, etc. Very brief summary of my last 6 months and first 6 months with programming. Working 80 hours a week on this...